# get all record with number of one to many table count

Tags: sql

I got two table, one is member another is member_status table. I need to get the count of the number of member in the same status.

member

```
+----+-------------+-----------+---------+--------+--------+--------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | full_name   | mobile_no | address | status | remark | edit_user_id | user_id | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+-------------+-----------+---------+--------+--------+--------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | John Doe    | 123       |         | 1      |        |            1 |       1 | 2014-06-19 15:51:08 | 2014-06-19 15:51:08 |
|  2 | Michael Bay | 123       |         | 1      |        |            1 |       1 | 2014-06-19 15:51:08 | 2014-06-19 15:51:08 |
|  3 | Hey Hey     | 123       |         | 3      |        |            1 |       1 | 2014-06-19 15:51:08 | 2014-06-19 15:51:08 |
+----+-------------+-----------+---------+--------+--------+--------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

member_status

```
+----+---------------------+----------------------+--------+--------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | name                | description          | status | edit_user_id | user_id | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+---------------------+----------------------+--------+--------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | Visitor             | Visitor              | 1      |            1 |       1 | 2014-06-19 15:51:08 | 2014-06-19 15:51:08 |
|  3 | Member              | Member               | 1      |            1 |       1 | 2014-06-19 15:51:08 | 2014-06-19 15:51:08 |
|  4 | Level 1             | Level 1              | 1      |            1 |       1 | 2014-06-19 15:51:08 | 2014-06-19 15:51:08 |
| 11 | Level 12            | Level 12             | 1      |            1 |       1 | 2014-07-03 17:27:00 | 2014-07-03 17:27:00 |
+----+---------------------+----------------------+--------+--------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I had tried this query, but it is NOT CORRECT output...

```
select `member_status`.`name`, count(*) as totalNum
from member
right join `member_status` on (member.`status` = `member_status`.id) 
group by `member_status`.name
```

This is output I would like to have it

```
+---------------------+----------+
| name                | totalNum |
+---------------------+----------+
| Level 1             |        0 |
| Level 12            |        0 |
| Member              |        1 |
| Visitor             |        2 |
+---------------------+----------+
```

However, somehow, the output is this one

```
+---------------------+----------+
| name                | totalNum |
+---------------------+----------+
| Level 1             |        1 |
| Level 12            |        1 |
| Member              |        1 |
| Visitor             |        2 |
+---------------------+----------+
```

Can anyone please advice?

Comment: do u have any insert query script for above tables else sqlfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try
`select * from member right join member_status on (member.status = member_status.id)`
and you'll see NULL-s for member fields.
That's why you are getting more counts then you want.

One of the solutions:
`select member_status.name, count(member.id) as totalNum 
from member right join member_status on (member.status = member_status.id) 
group by member_status.name`

or

`select member_status.name, sum(case when member.id is null then 0 else 1 END) as totalNum 
from member right join member_status on (member.status = member_status.id) 
group by member_status.name`

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT S.NAME, SUM(CASE WHEN S.ID = T.STATUS THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
FROM member_status S, member T 
GROUP BY S.NAME`

Answer (score 0):

You need correlated sub-query for such result:

```
select      member_status.name, m.m_qty AS totalNum

from        member_status
left join   (
                select      member.status, count(member.id) AS m_qty
                from        member
                group by    member.status
            ) AS m ON (m.status = member_status.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this :

```
select `member_status`.`name`, CASE WHEN member.`status` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE count(*) as totalNum END
from member
right join `member_status` on (member.`status` = `member_status`.id) 
group by `member_status`.name, member.`status`
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as totalNum END
from members
right join `member_status` on (member.`status` = `status`' at line 1